# Functor laws in Agda

Tags: agda

Traditionally functors in Haskell are supposed to support identity and composition laws. In Agda these laws should be formalized, but the standard library only ships `RawFunctor`s yet (i.e. an fmap without laws). In the process of formalizing functors a few questions arise:

Should functors support congruence in general?

1. Yes: On arbitrary `Setoid`s or just `Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.setoid`?
2. Yes: Should a functor take or provide a `Function.Equality.Π`?
3. No: Which identity function should the identity law support? All of them (i.e. `(id′ : A → A) → id′ ≗ id`)?
4. No: How should a function ask for a functor that supports congruence?
5. No: What (real world?) functors do not support congruence?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

**Functors on equivalence relations**

If a mapping `F : Setoid ℓ ℓ → Setoid ℓ ℓ` is to be turned into a functor, then congruence does not follow from other laws. For instance, `F` could map an `s` with the trivial relation to `Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.setoid (Carrier s)` and set `fmap = id`. Then, congruence does not hold in general. So as soon as the first equivalence relation is something different from equality, congruence is not a consequence.

**Functors on propositional equality**

It seems that all congruence proofs have the same structure: induction on the syntax of the `fmap` function. Thus they fall in the same category as free theorems. Other than something similar to [lightweight free theorems](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.LightweightFreeTheorems), there is no automatic way to obtain such a proof.

More answers welcome.